What exactly is the relation “cousin uncle” in Reservation Dogs?
Cheese refers to the older relative he lives with in the first season and a half as his “cousin uncle.” I’m curious what the term means in this context. Wiktionary defines it as:

Male first cousin of one's parent; one's male first cousin once removed in a higher generation.

but also attributes the use only to Mennonites and English speakers in India/Pakistan.¹
Can anyone speak to the meaning of the term among the Muscogee people?


Without citation or attribution for this latter, I wonder if it’s related to the use of -uncle and -aunt as honorific titles used by at least some Indian/Pakistani speakers when referring to their adult friends to their children. I had a neighbor who would refer to my and my wife when speaking to her son as “Don-uncle” and “Nalleli-aunt.”


Don't know about this film, but even in Britain 50+ years ago children were taught to address family friends as "Uncle X" and "Auntie Y" - calling adults by their given name alone was a no-no.
